# remove duplicate values with preference for removal from largest group

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a tibble for which I want to remove the rows with duplicate values, but with a *preference for removal from the largest group*.

**Example data:**

```
(tb <- tibble(group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 3:1),
             value = c(4,2,1,1,2,1)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 A         2
3 A         1
4 B         1
5 B         2
6 C         1
```

Here, the values 1 and 2 are duplicated. For the case of 1, I want to have it removed from the 2 larger groups (A and B), and keep the value for C. Likewise, the rows for value 2 should be removed from group A. (When group sizes are tied, it does not matter from which group the row is removed.)

**Desired result**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 B         2
3 C         1
```

Using `tb %>% filter(!duplicated(value))` works to remove the dups, but does not take into account the group sizes:

**Actual result**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 A         2
3 A         1
```

Is there an (easy) tidyverse to take group sizes into account when removing the duplicates?

Comment: If A has 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, and B has 5, 2, 2, then what should be the result? I.e., initially group A is larger, but if we remove 1's first, then B would be larger when considering removal of 2's. In that case also the order of numbers to remove starts to matter, so perhaps only the initial sizes matter?

Comment: @JuliusVainora good point. My data does not contain any duplicates within a group and the overall amount of duplicates is <3%. Therefore, using the initial sizes would be good solution, as the group sizes will not change dramatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```
tb %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(size = n()) %>% group_by(value) %>%
  filter(size == min(size))

group value  size
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A         4     3
2 B         2     2
3 C         1     1
```

Comment: BTW, you could consider to use `slice(which.min(size))` instead of the `filter` in your last line.

Comment: Is there an advantage in doing it like you propose?

Comment: At least you don't have to repeat the 'size' variable name, but I don't know about any performance gains. In this case the variable consists of only 4 characters, but in other cases I think the method I proposed will be more concise eventually.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for the input!

Comment: that works neatly! Combined, I used this solution: ```tb %>% add_count(group) %>% group_by(value) %>% slice(which.min(n))```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
 tb <- tibble(group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 3:1),
 value = c(4,2,6,1,2,1))

group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 A         2
3 A         6
4 B         1
5 B         2
6 C         1

tb %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(group == max(group))

group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 A         6
3 B         2
4 C         1

tb <- tibble(group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 3:1),
              value = c(4,2,1,1,2,1))

 group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 A         2
3 A         1
4 B         1
5 B         2
6 C         1

tb %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(group == max(group))

group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         4
2 B         2
3 C         1
```

Comment: group_by(value) is a good idea, but this solution does not work in my case when I have different group names, as this kind of hard-codes from which groups to do the removal (instead of actually checking their sizes). It will not work for instance for ```tb <- tibble(group = rep(LETTERS[3:1], times = 3:1), value = c(4,2,1,1,2,1))```

Comment: maybe?    tb %>% group_by(group) %>% add_tally() %>% group_by(value) %>% filter(n==min(n))